# Android: how to make an image viewer with ListView at bottom

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have received a requirement make an image viewer with the listview at bottom like this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aC4OFRxk988 but I don't know the name of that controller to research. Please help me. Thanks

Comment: Looks like a horizontal ScollView with a vertical ScrollView below it to me.

Comment: may be you are looking for viewPager

Comment: Check this image slider: https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider

Comment: @ButaniVijay is right, it seems to be a `ScrollView` containing a `ViewPager`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think viewpager and listview.

and dynamic scale image view are setmatrix.

simply reply. i can't add comment at your post....

if want more hint reply me.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me a library or the way to make it?

Comment: [https://github.com/leenamung/TestScaleImage](https://github.com/leenamung/TestScaleImage)
please download project and parse it.
my english skill bad, my best way.
and this version is many bugs. just refer

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

You can find here some custom implementations.

Test the demo app from the play store and check which one has the closest functionality to the one you desire. Then take a deep breath and try to understand how it's done.